# How to highlight column which has next column as empty

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

So far I tried using existing rule which will highlight empty cells.

[image: Existing Rule]

Which will highlight empty cells only.

[image: Produced Result -]

However, I want to highlight column before empty cell

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data starts in cell A2.

- Select cell A2
- On the Home tab ribbon, click on Conditional Formatting
- Select "New Rule"
- Select your rule type as "Use a formula to determine which cells to
  format"
- In the text box, enter `=AND(A2<>"",A3="")`
- Click the format button
- Click on the Fill tab and select your highlight color
- Click OK until the windows close
- Use the format Painter on the home ribbon to copy the conditional
  formatting from cell A2 to any other cells you want to follow this
  rule